# dynamic_cast a non-const ref to a const ref. cppreference.com's explanation seems odd

Tags: c++, casting, dynamic-cast

I was refreshing my memory on the various types of casting available and came across the following on cppreference.com (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast):

> **1) If the type of *expression* is the exactly new_type or a less cv-qualified version of *new_type*, the result is *expression*.**

Referring to the structure

```
dynamic_cast < new_type > ( expression )
```

I interpreted that to mean that, for example, attempting a dynamic_cast of a non-const reference to a const reference of the same type would actually yield the non-const reference and therefore allow me to call its non-const members, **which is the opposite of what I'd expect**. I wrote the following noddy piece of code to check that out:

```
#include<iostream>

class Base
{
  int value;
public:
  Base():value(0){};

  virtual void ShowVal() const
  {
    printf("Value is %d\n", value);
  }

  virtual void SetVal(int val)
  {
    value = val;
  }

};

int main ()
{
  Base b;
  Base& rB = b;

  b.ShowVal();

  (dynamic_cast<const Base&>(rB)).SetVal(2); //fails where (dynamic_cast<Base&>(rB)).SetVal(2); is obviously fine.

  b.ShowVal();
}
```

As I'd have expected anyway, this *doesn't* compile and I get the error

```
blah.cpp:28:3: error: member function 'SetVal' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const Base', but function is not marked const
(dynamic_cast<const Base&>(rB)).SetVal(2);
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I suppose the question I'm meandering towards is: Have I misunderstood the rule above? And if so, what is it *actually* saying and is there a similarly basic example that demonstrates it?

Thanks. (In the meantime I'm going to read it again, and if I realise I've misread it then I'll quickly delete this question and commence facepalming...)

Comment: You may use const_cast to add/remove cv qualifier.

Comment: I'm aware of that but it's the explanation above that confuses me rather than how to modify constness of an object. Thanks though.

Comment: FYI, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast has been updated to hopefully be a little clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so obvious from the way that's written, but the conversion still takes place. It just means that the object you get from the conversion (the pointer or reference) is the same as the one denoted by `expression`. The cast expression is of `const` type though because that's what you converted it to.

Here's what it looks like in the C++11 standard:

> If the type of `v` is the same as `T`, or it is the same as `T` except that the class object type in `T` is more cv-qualified than the class object type in `v`, the result is `v` (converted if necessary).

Note the "converted if necessary".

You might wonder why it even bothers saying that the result is `expression`? For most `dynamic_cast`s, the result is *not* `expression`. Consider casting from a pointer to base class to a pointer to derived class. You don't get the same pointer out of it. Instead, you get a pointer to the derived subobject.

Comment: "Converted as necessary" presumably meaning "converted to its more cv-qualified state"? If so, that's consistent with exactly what I'd expect, and it also fills in the gap I think is left by the excerpt above! Thanks :-)

Comment: @splrs That's exactly what it means.

Answer (score 0):

It says the type of *expression* can be ***less*** cv-qualified than *new-type*. The type of the result is still *new-type* (the value is *expression*). Because that's specified.

Comment: Their problem is with it saying that the result is `expression`, as though no conversion has taken place.

Comment: Your explanation makes perfect sense and doesn't appear contradictory. My issue is that the actual wording is "the result is expression". This to me implies type and value, as @sftrabbit understands I have read it.